# Using timezone with openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, django, datetime, openpyxl

I need to add a date in an excel file.
I use timezones on these dates. It works very well with django rest framework. (My GET requests return the date with this format: `2022-07-23T13:19:59+02:00`) Same in Django admin, the Europe/Paris timezone is well taken into account (**+02:00**).

However, when I use openpyxl, the indicated time is 2h late (it takes the UTC timezone).

```py
sheet.append([date_recorded.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")])
```

Same thing if I print this date in console. (`2022-07-11 15:19:50+00:00`)

How to correct this?

Comment: Excel has no concept of timezones so you'll need to do your own offsetting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply convert it to your desired zone like this:

```
from dateutil import tz
utctime = "YOUR CURRENT VALUE OF DATETIME"
from_zone = tz.gettz("UTC")
to_zone = tz.gettz("yourzone")
utctime = utctime.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
new_time = utctime.astimezone(to_zone)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using django, you can use built-in `get_current_timezone` to convert datetime objects to the local timezone:

```py
from django.utils import get_current_timezone

timezone = get_current_timezone()
date_recorded = date_recorded.astimezone(timezone)
sheet.append([date_recorded.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")])
```