# Django Rest Framework - datetime sent as str gets changed to different timezone when being saved to database?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I sent the following:

```
{'ticker': 'XYZ', 'last_price': 394.05, 'last_date_time': '2022-10-04 15:57:18'}
```

When it was saved in DB:

```
ticker: XYZ
last_price: 394.05
last_date_time: 2022-10-04 11:57:18
```

I am not sure how or why this gets changed.

models.py

```
class StockPriceModel(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, db_index=True)
    last_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_date_time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The `auto_now_add` field is also showing incorrect time.

It doesn't correspond to my date time setup in settings as below:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dubai'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: The time being sent is interpreted as Asia/Dubai and then normalised to UTC to be stored in the database…

Comment: @deceze very interesting thank you. Guess I need to change it to a different timezone at the time of retrival.

Comment: in case if you want to change timezone after retrieving data from db only. this might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73231751/16250404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django stores datetime in UTC timezone. See this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#overview) for details.
Since you specified `'Asia/Dubai'` as default timezone. Django considers received value as 'Asia/Dubai' time and converts it to UTC before saving. If you need to change this logic try to use `default_timezone` argument in serializer's [`DateTimeField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield) field:

```
class MySerializer:
    last_date_time = DateTimeField(default_timezone=pytz.utc)
```

Comment: Thanks, any way to leave the datetime as is when sending the data? There will be multiple timezones and I would like to keep them all as is. I can possibly add another column with zone/country. Or I change them to a different time zone when retrieving as per the zone/country from the databse field.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you will need to add separate column to the table with TZ info.